# The trait `std::ops::Fn<(char,)>` is not implemented for `T`

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to implement the greps project and I am stuck at the search function.

```
fn search<'a, T>(query: &T, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }
    results
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
rustc 1.18.0 (03fc9d622 2017-06-06)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::ops::Fn<(char,)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:39:17
   |
39 |         if line.contains(query) {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Fn<(char,)>` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::ops::Fn<(char,)>` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::FnOnce<(char,)>` for `&T`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `&T`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::ops::FnOnce<(char,)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:39:17
   |
39 |         if line.contains(query) {
   |                 ^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::FnOnce<(char,)>` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where T: std::ops::FnOnce<(char,)>` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `&T`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:57:40
   |
57 |         assert_eq!(vec!["KAMEHAMEHA"], search(query, contents));
   |                                        ^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   |
   = note: `str` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   = note: required by `search`
```

Why do I need the `Fn` trait? Adding that trait isn't solving my problem. I am using generics, and I know I don't really need generics here but I am trying to understand the topic.

Here is the full code on Rust [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ca11eb8e51982f63a61ff05c542ec0db&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: The error message is horribly confusing, and unrelated AFAICT; might want to file a bug report on that. The real problem is that `str::contains()` wants a type with [the `Pattern` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html), but `&Path` doesn't implement that trait. `&str` does, however, so [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f6cf176acc0e25ff18acb8f9137f2314&version=stable&backtrace=0) works, but I don't know if that's really what you want (hence posting a comment rather than answer)...

Comment: Hey that does solve my problem. :D One doubt, why is query Path here?

Comment: Because `run` has `where T: std::convert::AsRef<std::path::Path>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem (or one of them) is in this function:

```
fn search<'a, T>(query: &T, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }
    results
}
```

The function `line.contains()` expects an argument that implements the trait `Pattern`. But your `T` parameter is unconstrained. The error is a little confusing because you probably don't care about the `Fn` and `FnOnce` implementations, which just happen to be supertypes of `Pattern`.

The next problem you'll face is that `Pattern` itself is not stabilized yet, so you can't use it explicitly unless you switch to a nightly build of the compiler. Otherwise, you can constrain `T` so that it can at least be turned into something else that already implements `Pattern`, such as `&str`:

```
fn search<'a, T: 'a>(query: &'a T, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> 
    where &'a T: Into<&'a str>
{
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query.into()) {
            results.push(line);
        }
    }
    results
}
```

You'll still have more errors after this, but hopefully this gets you past the most confusing one.